# I can't solve the runtime error for this BST menu driven program

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Below is the menu driven program for various operation in BST. The major problem I am getting is when I free function runs in delete function please help and update the given program. Whenever I try to delete any node after insertion, the program abruptly ends. I tried to debug but the problem still persists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct btNode
{
    int data;
    struct btNode *right;
    struct btNode *left;
};

int found;
struct btNode *temp2;
struct btNode *create(int);
struct btNode *insert(struct btNode *, int);
void inorder(struct btNode *);
void preorder(struct btNode *);
void postorder(struct btNode *);
void delete (struct btNode *, int);

int main()
{
    int choice, item;
    struct btNode *root = NULL;

    do
    {
        printf("\nChoose one of the options:\n");
        printf("1. Insert 2. Delete 3. Inorder 4. Postorder 5. Preorder 6. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEnter any number to insert:");
            scanf("%d", &item);
            root = insert(root, item);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\nEnter any number to delete:");
            scanf("%d", &item);
            delete(root, item);
            break;

        case 3:
            inorder(root);
            break;

        case 4:
            postorder(root);
            break;

        case 5:
            preorder(root);
            break;

        case 6:
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nWRONG INPUT");
        }
    } while (choice != 6);

    return 0;
}

struct btNode *create(int num)
{
    struct btNode *temp1 = (struct btNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct btNode));
    temp1->data = num;
    temp1->left = NULL;
    temp1->right = NULL;
    return temp1;
}

struct btNode *search(struct btNode *root, int num)
{
    struct btNode *temp1 = root;

    while (temp1 != NULL)
    {
        if (temp1->data == num)
        {
            found = 1;
            return temp1;
        }

        else
        {
            if (temp1->data >= num)
            {
                temp2 = temp1;
                temp1 = temp1->left;
            }

            else
            {
                temp2 = temp1;
                temp1 = temp1->right;
            }
        }
    }
    found = 0;
}

struct btNode *insert(struct btNode *root, int num)
{
    struct btNode *temp1 = create(num);
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = temp1;
        printf("%d inserted\n", root->data);
    }
    else
    {
        temp2 = root;
        while (temp2 != NULL)
        {
            if (temp2->data >= num)
            {
                if (temp2->left)
                {
                    temp2 = temp2->left;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp2->left = temp1;
                    printf("%d inserted\n", temp2->left->data);
                    break;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (temp2->right)
                {
                    temp2 = temp2->right;
                }

                else
                {
                    temp2->right = temp1;
                    printf("%d inserted\n", temp2->right->data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}

void delete (struct btNode *root, int num)
{
    struct btNode *temp1 = search(root, num);
    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("element not found");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        if (temp1->left == NULL && temp1->right == NULL)
        {
            free(temp1);
        }

        if (temp1->left != NULL && temp1->right == NULL)
        {
            if (temp2->left = temp1)
            {
                temp2->left = temp1->left;
                free(temp1);
            }

            if (temp2->right = temp1)
            {
                temp2->right = temp1->left;
                free(temp1);
            }
        }

        if (temp1->left == NULL && temp1->right != NULL)
        {
            if (temp2->left = temp1)
            {
                temp2->left = temp1->right;
                free(temp1);
            }

            if (temp2->right = temp1)
            {
                temp2->right = temp1->right;
                free(temp1);
            }
        }

        if (temp1->left != NULL && temp1->right != NULL)
        {
            struct btNode *node1 = temp1;
            struct btNode *node2 = temp1->right;

            while (node2->left != NULL)
            {
                node1 = node2;
                node2 = node2->left;
            }
            temp1->data = node2->data;
            temp1 = node2;
            free(temp1);
        }
    }
}

void inorder(struct btNode *r)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        printf("Tree is empty");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        if (r->left)
            inorder(r->left);
        printf("%d ", r->data);
        if (r->right)
            inorder(r->right);
    }
}

void preorder(struct btNode *r)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        printf("Tree is empty");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("%d ", r->data);
        if (r->left)
            preorder(r->left);
        if (r->right)
            preorder(r->right);
    }
}

void postorder(struct btNode *r)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        printf("Tree is empty");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        if (r->left)
            postorder(r->left);
        if (r->right)
            postorder(r->right);
        printf("%d ", r->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.  If you are coding in an IDE, then it very likely has one built in.  If not, then there are command-line debuggers such as `gdb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `delete()` function has errors at several levels.  Among these:

- general API:  deletion can change the tree's root node, but you make no provision for that.  At minimum deletion changes the root node when the only node of a one-node tree is deleted, but with an approach such as yours, the root node will change whenever you delete the value that it contains.
- Implementation flaw: in a similar vein, when you perform a search and discover the target value in the root node, you do not set the (very poorly named) `temp2` file-scope variable.  When that search is performed in the context of a deletion, it may result in either `delete()` attempting to dereference a null pointer, or in it corrupting the tree by modifying a random node as if it were the parent on the target node.
- Implementation flaw: when you delete a leaf node (other than the root), you need to set its parent's pointer to it to `NULL`.
- Bad code: you have several `if` statements in `delete()` that use `=` where they mean `==`.
- Poor style: do not rely on global variables (`temp2`, `found`).  Where you want your functions to return multiple values then either use structures or endow the functions with out parameters.